# Midi instrument index python

Tags: python, parsing, midi, midi-instrument, mido

I have some midi files. Each midi file has some instruments. I need to know what instruments each midi file consists. I have found some `python` libs that can parse midi files such as [mido](https://mido.readthedocs.io). For example, here is the result of parsing one midi file:

[image]

I can see how many tracks in this midi file, but I don't know what instruments are playing each track. Here is midi instrument [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI#Piano). Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: You have to look at the bank select and program change messages inside each track.

Comment: What do you mean "change messages"?

Comment: I mean "program change messages" (messages that change the program.

Answer (score 0):

In MIDI instruments are known as programs and each track can contain
multiple instruments. Although they may not overlap (unless they use
different channels). Here is Python code to display when in a track
each program plays. The code assumes that the track is stored in the
`track` variable:

```
time = 0
for msg in track:
    time += msg.time
    if msg.type == 'program_change':
        program = msg.program
        print(f'Time {time:6}, program {program:3} starts.')
```